# How to apply changes on a different base path using git

Tags: git

The project I'm working with was build using ant in the past. A few weeks ago it was modularized and migrated to maven. Thus the project structure changed and the `src` directory paths. From e.g. `/src` to `/module-A/src/main/java`.

So the repository looks like this

```
       mavenization        master
           V                 |
                             V
o----o-----o-----o-----o-----o      <-- maven project with module-A/src/main/java
    \
     \
      o-----o-----A                 <-- still an ant project with `/src`
                  ^
                  |
           maintenance branch
```

The `maintenance branch` is the one that was released weeks ago and is now the bugfix branch for production.

My problem is that I have to fix a bug in the `mainenance branch` and of course apply it to the master.But this doesn't work, because the project structure changed with the `mavenization` commit.

Well, the directory structure under the `/module-A/src/main/java` is the same as on the `maintenance branch`'s `/src` directory. But since the base directory differs I guess a cherry-pick is not possible or do you know some option?

Of course I could merge the files manually or using a tool like WinMerge, but I'm looking for a better solution using git.

How can I apply the changes of commit `A` with a different base path to the `master` branch?

Answer (score 3):

Make a patch of the `mavenization` commit. Suppose the commit hash is `abc123`.

```
git format-patch -1 abc123
```

And you will get a patch named `0001.xxx.patch`.

Switch to `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Apply the patch:

```
git am 0001.xxx.patch --directory=module-A/
```

`git apply` also works this way.